# How to add rewrite rule for multiple applications hosted in one Azure App Service

Tags: reactjs, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I am hosting four different applications in one Azure App Service - 2 static reactjs web sites and 2 .NET CORE APIs.

The applications are set in different virtual directories:

```
/
/api
/admin
/admin/api
```

I am trying to write a redirect rule so that I can use the react-router routing for the static sites but also be able to use the .NET Core API routing.

This is what I tried for the admin route but the only thing that works is the routing for the static site, not the API

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="ReactRoutes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="admin/(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="api/(.*)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/admin/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: this only work which admin because you set URL pattern to admin/(.*). if you want to work with admin and api you could use this rule `<rule name="ReactRoutes" stopProcessing="true"><match url="(.*)" /><conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"><add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="api/(.*)|admin/(.*)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/admin/" />
        </rule>`

Comment: Hey @JalpaPanchal
I tried your solution but unfortunately it didn't work. I was able to access my api and it's swagger but when I try to navigate to some of the react's routes it didn't work. 
I tried setting up the web.config file only in the /admin folder where I set this redirect rules based on your recommendations with the following rule for the API but it still didn't work: <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="api/(.*)" negate="true" />
I also tried setting up the whole rule you recommended in the root directory but again with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the rules for the admin by writing the following web.config which I hosted in /admin root

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite Admin React Routes" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/admin/api(.*)$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/admin/index.html" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```